# Are costs related to provisioned IOPS part of "No Instance Type" cost group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In AWS Cost Management, when we group costs by "Instance Type" for RDS Service I can see the `No Instance Type ***` is getting a really large portion of the total cost. In my case, it's around 45%.

At the bottom of the page we can see an explanation:

> ***This category includes costs (e.g., data transfer in/out) that are not directly attributable to a specific Instance Type.

What can be part of that except data transfer? Provisioned IOPS maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the “No Instance type”, please choose the **Group by from the Instance type to the Usage type**. you can see the cost StorageIOUsage, instancetype , ChargedBackupUsage, etc.

just give a try you will get the more detail..

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Now, I can see `PIOPS-Storage`, `Multi-AZ-PIOPS` & `RDS:PIOPS`...

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

As I found out today, it can also be attributed to buying a Reserved Instance.     That is not intuitive at all.